# Reduce execution time in labview math script realtime

Tags: real-time, labview

for executing this matlab code in mscript node on realtime target took 2700 microsecond, I need to finish computation within 1000 micro second. Please help me to achieve the goal. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code and error messages as text in your question and do not post a screenshot of it. This makes it easier for others to copy the code and to reproduce the problem. Also, the link to the image might become invalid after some time.

Comment: @Mozahler, it is not possible to include LabVIEW code as text, and no error message is mentioned in the body of the question... I guess, the only question is to decrease computation time. Which is, of course, questionable whether someone would like just to solve this problem...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification/explanation.

Comment: I think the `mscript` code should be added to the question as text. I don't see any of `in2` being referenced in the diagram, so I suspect there's more to that node than what is visible.

Comment: Did you try to implement same calculations, but using just pure LabVIEW funcitons? Becase as far as I know, Mathscript node gives some overhead during execution. But, it's good to try, and compare.

Comment: @kosist the function is too big to present as a labview G code

Comment: You can post any size of LabVIEW code here by making it into a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/) - unless the image upload function says the actual file is too big? Anyway, @JoeFriedrichsen is correct that you need to post the whole mscript code, because your image shows that this returns a value `V` but it doesnt show where `V` is calculated.